# How can I see the native code generated by CLR?

Tags: .net, jvm, native-code

Is there any way to see the native code generated by CLR?

In java there is a option "***-XX:+PrintOptoAssembly***" to see the native code compiled by JIT. So is there any similar thing for CLR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could use WinDbg+[SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) to dissassemble the JIT's generated code. More specifically, you may find that the`!u` command especially useful for your needs:

> Displays an annotated disassembly of a managed method specified either by a **MethodDesc** structure pointer for the method or by a code address within the method body. The **U** command displays the entire method from start to finish, with annotations that convert metadata tokens to names.